# How to handle tweepy's "Stream encountered HTTP error: 406" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

so guys, i know that the `Stream found HTTP error: 406` error only occurs when the user is wrong or doesn't exist, the problem is that only this is printed, it doesn't say on which line it occurs, so I would like to know how to deal with such an error so the code stops whenever it occurs as in my code if the user is wrong then the code will keep displaying the error and execution will continue infinitely

```
class Linstener(tweepy.Stream):

                
    def on_status(self, status):
        tweets = f"{status.user.screen_name}: {status.text}"
        print(tweets)


stream_tweet = Linstener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

              
try:
    stream_tweet.filter(follow=['user'])
except:
    stream_tweet.disconnect() # i tried to disconnect here in case the user is wrong or doesn't exist, however, as you imagine, it didn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

if it did not work in the `try` statement, then the code has not connected.

This would mean that the disconnect would fail in the `except` section (given that it was never connected in the first place).

So to use this for the try statement:

```py
try:
    stream_tweet.filter(follow=['user'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: i did this procedure and I kept having the `Stream encountered HTTP error: 406` endlessly

Comment: which line is the error being thrown ?  in the try block or before it ?

Comment: that's the problem, it's not told which line the error is on, just `Stream encountered HTTP error: 406` is printed

Comment: there error must occur at some point. use the debugger to identify this. At this stage i am **guessing** that it is prior to the `try` block.  Because there is insufficient code to replicate the problem.

Comment: i will debug now. about the code, that's literally what i posted, i just didn't put the api key settings

Comment: i just debugged the code and unfortunately i didn't get any information from which line the error comes

Comment: this means that `Stream found HTTP error: 406` is a valid response in the code. One (simple) method of dealing with this is with an `if` statement.

Comment: i solved it by implementing the method of looking for the ID by the user, and putting it in a try/except. so, if the user didn't exist, the except would print saying that the user doesn't exist and after that i put a break